# How to launch a Chrome App from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Typically an app is opened from *chrome://apps/* or in the *button Chrome apps*, but how would from an external Chrome Extension?

My extension:

```
->manifest.json
->background.js
```

My app:

```
->manifest.json
->background.js
```

Then, **how to launch my app from my extension**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the docs: [`chrome.management.launchApp`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp)

```
chrome.management.launchApp("YourAppsId", function(){
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  else console.log("App launched");
});
```

You will need the `"management"` permission for that.

---

Edit: see Daniel Herr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071101/934239) for a less invasive solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you own both items you can just use messaging to open the app window when receiving a message from the extension. This does not have a permissions warning that will repel users like management. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

First, add this to both manifests:

```
"externally_connectable": { "ids": [ "idoftheotheritem" ] }
```

Then, listen for messages in your app and create a app window:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("app.html");
}
```

Finally, send from the extension:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("idoftheapp", { launch: true })
```

Comment: Great suggestion! If this works, I recommend the OP to change the accepted answer