# Chrome Packaged Apps: Opening another app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am wondering whether there is any JS API to start another chrome app on button click event in a chrome packaged app.

Comment: Depends. Do you control the other app (i.e. can you add code to it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, no, you can't invoke another app.

However, if you control both apps, you can set the second app to expect an [external message](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external).

You can add `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` listener to the second app's event page script, and send a message with the app ID from the first to wake the second app and launch the app window. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071101/934239) for more details.

---

In general, an *extension* can do this task and more thanks to the [`management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management). It is, however, unavailable for Apps as of now.

Feature request to add this API for apps: [#455550](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455550)

Comment: Thanks @Xan for your answer. I want to make my app general as in it should be able to invoke other apps like text editor, calculator, etc. Is there any way if I have the app ID for the app I want to invoke. Also, is there any way I can know the past history of the apps that were opened by the user.

Comment: Extensions can do that, but not apps. You need the `management` API. I edited the question; you have no hope of achieving this currently in an app.

Comment: Oh, and by the way. It is cumbersome to install, but you can do it with an app AND a helper extension.

Comment: Hopefully we will get inline install from apps: crbug.com/426912