# Is there a way to launch chrome packaged app from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a chrome packaged app and chrome extension, both of them communicate with one another, and i want to lunch my packaged app from a chrome extension, is there any way to do it?

Note:
I've tried using the launchApp method of [chrome management api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), but for some unknown reason the chrome.management is **undefined** in my chrome extension JS code, although i have specified management permission in my manifest file like so:

`"permissions": ["management"]`

Does anyone have a idea what is the problem, or there are any other way i can do it ?

Thanks for help:)

Comment: Please format your question properly. I will then answer. Also, important thing to clarify - do you also develop the app, or is it a third-party app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons for not being able to use `chrome.management`.

1. You have not reloaded your extension properly
2. You are trying to call this from a content script; you can't do that, since a content script has very restricted access to Chrome API. You need to message a background page to do this for you.

That said, there is a better way to do it if you write both your extension and your app. `"management"` permission is a big hammer and will generate a warning to the user on installation.

Instead, you can send a cross-extension message to your app. It will wake it up and you can launch your main window from there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071101/934239) for details.

Comment: It works perfectly, just a small addition "chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener" should be inside "background.js" file, thnx @Xan