# How to open a chrome app using chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am a newbie so bear with me.
I am starting to learn how to create Chrome Extensions and Chrome Apps. I found this on Github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window

I can also create a [simple chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).
My question is how can I open/run/call a chrome app using my custom chrome extension?

Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a Chrome App from a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198322/how-to-launch-a-chrome-app-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: Try using [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between your app and your extension. As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019529/5995040), an app and extension can send message between them.